# Can a table look like this?

Tags: html, css

Can a table look like this be made?

```
+---------------+
|   |   |   |   |
+---------------+
|     |   |     |
+---------------+
|   |   |   |   |
+---------------+
```

If I do

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then `abc` is inserted in just one `<td>`.

This jdfiddle shows the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/EskrV/

How is such a table made, if it is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>1</td>
        <td colspan=3>2</td>
        <td colspan=3>3</td>
        <td colspan=3>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=4>a</td>
        <td colspan=4>b</td>
        <td colspan=4>c</td>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>1</td>
        <td colspan=3>2</td>
        <td colspan=3>3</td>
        <td colspan=3>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting alternative way to think about it.

Comment: Should I style it in some way? http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/EskrV/21/ The current two solution look different in output right now.

Comment: I think before you do that you should look at what it looks like with longer input, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/a8MdF/

Answer (score 9):

Add a `colspan` to the `<td>` with the 3 column table.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EskrV/18/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="4">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>b</td>
                <td>c</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: may need to also set the nested table `width` to `100%`

Comment: That will probably be the case, but that should be handled via CSS.

Comment: @Michael Irigoyen : Very cool! I assume `colspan="4"` I should move to css too?

Comment: No, `colspan` is an HTML attribute.

Comment: Colspan is an HTML property of the table tag, CSS doesn't support it. Keep it in the HTML.

Comment: text-align:center; on the TDs finish the job.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can: http://jsfiddle.net/XqKRR/ (without nested tables)
However I've got that strage feeling that you're trying to use tables for something that is not a tabular data, am I right? If so, maybe a CSS and `display: table[-row|-cell]` will be a better soultion?

Comment: It actually is for tabular data =) But `display: table[-row|-cell]` sounds mighty interesting.

Comment: If it is for tabular data then stay with `<table>` elemnet. CSS `display` property is useful when you need table-like behaviour for non-tabular structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested <div>s then use css to set the width of each div.